# What is the correct approach to an AJAX POST and a resource controller in laravel (5.6)?

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel-5.6

So I'm totally new to javscript / ajax etc, and trying to get to grips with it. 
I've got various permutations of the AJAX call, enough to know that it's basically working.

Now specifically, I'm trying to get the content of my "form" to my database.

So...

**1. here's my route entry in web.php**

`Route::resources(['evaluations' => 'EvaluationsController']);`

**2. The create method of my resource controller presents the form, which has the javascript/ajax within it.**

```
public function create()
    {
       return view ('evaluations.create');
    }
```

**2. My ajax call in the form**

```
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"/evaluations",
    headers: { 'CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') },
    datatType : 'json',
    data:oneEvaluation,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false, 
    error: function (data)
      {
        console.log('AJAX call Failed');
      },
        success: function(data)
      {
        console.log('AJAX call success');
    },
});
```

**3. and the ajax call is routed to the store method**

```
 public function store(Request $request)
    {
      dd($request);
      return response()->json($response);
     ....
```

**4. And I get the right results**

even if the `dd();` did not work

```
AJAX call success
{status: "success", msg: null}
```

So now... where does the code to write to database belong? On the one hand, I would expect to develop my "store" function further, and hand over the new item id to a show method to show the positive results.

But the ajax call seems to still be in control and take things back to the original create view. Does that mean that the logic to do the database store operations are supposed to be written into the javascript in the form that was the source of the ajax call in the first place? I'm confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, Javascript is a client side language, and you cannot write directly to the database with a client side language. You need to use the server side language, in your case php. So your insert should happen in the Laravel Controller and return a success response.

You need to create a eloquent model for evaluations(Docs here ->https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent). Then in your Controller you can either call the Evaluations::create() method. Then when you call the save method on the Evaluations model, the data will be persisted to the database.